# Error installing NS-3 in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, python3

I am trying to install **NS-3** in my ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso, but during the attempted installation, when I run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0 python-gi python-gi-cairo python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-pygraphviz gir1.2-gtk-3.0 ipython3
```

I get this error:

```
E: Package 'python-gi' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-gi-cairo
```

Comment: [Looks like that package is only available for LTS releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-gi) 

Comment: NS-3 basic requirements `sudo apt install g++ python3 python3-dev pkg-config sqlite3 python3-setuptools git`  https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Ubuntu.2FDebian.2FMint ..... and for Netnim `qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake`

Answer (score 1):

`python-gi`, `python-cairo`, and `python3-gi-cairo` packages are not available in the default Ubuntu 21.04 repositories. Install `python-gi`, `python-cairo`, and `python3-gi-cairo` from Ubuntu 20.04 in Ubuntu 21.04. After that, install `gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0`, `python3-gi`, `python3-gi-cairo`, `python3-pygraphviz`, `gir1.2-gtk-3.0`, and `ipython3`.

Open the terminal and type:

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject/python-gi_3.36.0-1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject/python-gi-cairo_3.36.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt update   
sudo apt install python2   
sudo apt install ./python-gi_3.36.0-1_amd64.deb 
sudo apt install ./python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./python-gi-cairo_3.36.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0 python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-pygraphviz gir1.2-gtk-3.0 ipython3
```